# Spring & elasticsearch - Upsert a list of documents by specific field other than id

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

currently we are currently upserting a document based on the given id. However, we have recent changes that id will be autogenerated and we created a new field "main_id" that will serve as the primary id. How can we use upsert by "main_id" and not by id?
Here's the sample entity:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  private String id;

   private String mainId;

  private String name;
}
```

Currently, here's our implementation of the method:

```
 public void bulkCreateOrUpdate(final List<T> objectList) {

    List<UpdateQuery> updateList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T st: objectList) {
      UpdateQuery updateQuery = UpdateQuery.builder(st.getId())
          .withDocument(this.operations.getElasticsearchConverter().mapObject(st))
          .withDocAsUpsert(true)
          .build();
      updateList.add(updateQuery);
    }

    this.operations.bulkUpdate(updateList,
        this.operations.getIndexCoordinatesFor(this.entityClass));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docs-update.html) of Elasticsearch requires the document's id.

There is also the [update by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/docs-update-by-query.html), this is available in Spring Data Elasticsearch as well, but there you cannot pass in a new or updated document, but only a script to do the update.

So there is no way to do the update directly without using the id.